# How to prevent form submission based on date comparison

Tags: javascript, html, date, validation

I have a form in which I want to get a message and a date from the user. None of them can be empty upon the form submission.

I prevent form submission if the text field is empty(which is a CKeditor rich text field) and it works just fine. But, when I want to check the date( no dates before today can be submitted), it's not working!

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
<form name="submit_quote" id="submit_quote" action="{% url 'submit_quote' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input  type = 'date'
            class="input_date"
            placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
            name='when_is_required_date_{{ item.tag }}{{ item.id }}' 
            id='when_is_required_date_{{ item.tag }}{{ item.id }}' 
            required 
            min="2021-01-31"
            pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}">
    <textarea   name="message" 
                id="message" 
                class="form-control" 
                maxlength="4096" 
                onkeyup="textCounter(this,'counter',4096);" 
                autofocus required 
                style="height: 150px !important; " ></textarea>

    <input  
                disabled  
                maxlength="4" 
                size="4" 
                value="4096" 
                id="counter" 
                style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: none; right: 0px;" > 
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2 mx-auto">
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class=" btn btn-gray  text-light" 
                    style="background-color: #6c757d;"
                    type="submit"
                    value="Send" 
                    onClick="return empty()"
                    >
                    Send
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

And, I check the input fields like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
    var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    console.log('today: ', today);
    
    
    $('#submit_quote').submit(function() 
    {
        var dateControl = document.querySelector('.input_date');
        alert('input date: ', dateControl);

        
        if (jQuery("#cke_1_contents iframe").contents().find("body").text() === "" || dateControl <= today)   {
            alert('Please enter your message or a correct date.');
            return false;
        }       
    });
    
</script>
```

How to prevent a user from submitting dates before today or an empty date?

Answer (score 0):

If you compare 2 strings, you are comparing ascii code.

```
console.log(typeof dateControl); // String
console.log(typeof today); // String

var startOfToday = new Date(today).getTime();
console.log(typeof startOfToday); // Number
```